# how to launch other application with different process from my application

Tags: android

I would to like to ask how to launch other application with different processes from my application?

```
mIntent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(facebook package name);
mIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
mContext.startActivity( mIntent );
```

As above codes, I found that the facebook uses the same process as my application.
I would like to know that it is possible the facebook can be called with other process.

Comment: You mean Task instead process?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have the same sharedUserId and the same signature as the app you are launching, you are launching it is a different process. You cannot launch it in the same process even if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge the app in another apk will by default run in its own process. I guess when you say 'process' you mean 'task', if this is the case you can set the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) flag to the intent like this "mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);"